# QuickReturn Toolbar и WebView - тормоза

Tags: android, xml, webview, android-toolbar

Всем привет!
Решил сделать приложение для одного сайта, база -- WebView.
Было решено использовать QuickReturn Toolbar (который бы скрывался при прокрутке контента).

Создал вот такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_toster"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ru.SnowVolf.toster.TosterActivity"
style="@style/AppTheme">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Вроде бы я добился того чего хотел, toolbar скрывается и раскрывывается при прокрутке, но сам WV просто жестко фризит, прокрутка потеряла быстроту и плавность, да и нажатия кнопок на странице происходят с ощутимой задержкой.

Подозреваю, что это из-за   `NestedScrollView`, так как у если его убрать все приходит в норму. Без него у меня не удавалось заставить работать флаг `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`. Если прописать layout_behavior напрямую в WebView, то тулбар скрывается при прокрутке вниз, но не появляется при прокрутке вверх (до следующего перезапуска). 
Может кто направит на нужный путь?
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Оберните `WebView` в `ScrollView`

Comment: Тормоза пропали, но Toolbar теперь не скрывается

Comment: А вы добавили `behavior` в `ScrollView`?

Comment: Конечно. Все так же.

Comment: Если не поможет - https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: Попробовал со всеми вариантами - не едут лыжи и все тут. Ладно,  спасибо за попытку помочь. Буду думать как оптимищироваююю

Comment: *оптимизировать NestedScrollView.

Comment: Я вам скинул ссылку на библиотеку. Там есть README. Откройте и посмотрите самый последний скриншот.

Comment: По ссылке кастомный `WebView`. https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/ObservableWebView.java

Comment: Я его тоже пробовал. Бесполезно. Нашёл другое решение. Хоть и не самое изящное...